# Mouse to touch point driver, Emulate touch points with mice

Tags: windows-7, mouse

Are there any drivers to convert mice to touch points for multi-touch applications on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MultiTouch Vista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/) to do this. It's a little tricky to install, but following the instructions or the videos linked on the front page should get you there.